# Why is this instatiation of Functor not working?

Tags: haskell

To avoid conflicts with Prelude I define my own Functor class:

```
class F f where
    fm :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Why is this working ...

```
instance F ((->) a) where
    fm g f = g . f
```

GHCI:

```
*Main> fm (+1) (+10) $ 100
111
```

... but this isn't?

```
instance F ((->) Int) where
    fm g f = g . f
```

I don't get it - shouldn't the fact that I restrict the underlying set to functions mapping from `Int` be irrelevant to the mechanisms / definition of Functor?

The error message doesn't help:

```
    • Illegal instance declaration for ‘F ((->) Int)’
        (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
         where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
         and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
         Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
    • In the instance declaration for ‘F ((->) Int)’
  |
4 | instance F ((->) Int) where
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: The error message has some advice for you.  What is it?

Comment: Why doesn't `T` correspond to `((->) Int)` and `T a1` to `((->) Int) a1`? Basically that is what confuses me. Also logically I don't get why this doesn't work.

Comment: `Int` is not a type variable, that's why it doesn't correspond.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: yes, of course it isn't. I guess you wrote this before reading my comment - judging from the small difference of the timestamps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, and it *does* work sure enough if only you turn on that `-XFlexibleInstances` extension.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
class F f where fm :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
instance F ((->) Int) where fm g f = g . f
```

The reason it doesn't work without the extension is that standard Haskell has a strangely restricted notion of what's allowed as an instance. If you don't make the instance specific to a particular argument type, it actually works in Haskell98:

```
instance F ((->) a) where fm g f = g . f
```

I think this is really silly. The `FlexibleInstances` extension is thus extremely widespread, in fact I use it in almost every module. It is uncontroversial.

Comment: Though if you don't need it it is a sign of an especially lovely design, IMO, giving you some confidence each type and class has a self-contained, compositional meaning.  In fact, this question is a good example: generalize your instance, it says!

Comment: I still don't understand why I cannot interpret the error message such that `T` is representing `(->) Int`? In case of `(->) a b` (where it works fine): doesn't `T` correspond to `(->)` (and `a b` to `a1 a2`) as well as to `(->) a` (and `b` to `a1`)?

Comment: Not all of GHC's error messages are 100% accurate and precise. The actual rule (from section 4.3.2 of the Haskell 98 report) is that "The type (T u1 ... uk) must take the form of a type constructor T applied to simple type variables u1, ... uk; furthermore, T must not be a type synonym, and the ui must all be distinct."